# error activating environment via powershell

Tags: python, powershell, environment, stan

I'd cloned git repository and I'm trying to do steps according to readme file via Powershell.

Firstly, I'd run `conda env create -f environment.ymlt`
Using command `conda env list` I checked that new environment was created.

Secondly, I have to run `activate <env_name>` and I get the following output:

`>SET CMDSTAN_OLD=`

`>SET CMDSTAN=C:/Users/<user>/.conda/envs/<env_name>\Library\bin\cmdstan\`

I found folder cmdstanpy in my environment files
C:\Users<user>.conda\envs<env-name>\Lib\site-packages\cmdstanpy
and tried to install cmdstanpy `conda install -c conda-forge cmdstanpy`

Also I tried to add env libraries' files to path:
`C:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\<env_name>\Lib`
`C:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\<env_name>\Library`

But `activate <env_name>` had the same output

So the error is that I can't activate environment

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What was the error that you got? Can you please include it in your question.

Comment: Powershell uses environmental variable for cmdlets PSMODULEPATH.

Comment: The `SET` commands you're showing are for `cmd.exe` (batch files),  not PowerShell.

Comment: I can't activate environment

Comment: According to README file all steps I wrote about are made via Powershell. Should I try all the same steps via cmd?

Comment: Worth trying (I'm not familiar with [tag:stan]).